# How do I get rid of or change the footer in my child theme?

Tags: themes, child-theme, footer

I want to remove the default theme name and "powered by WP" text in the footer of every page. I've created a child theme to hold all my customizations from the original theme so that my customizations won't be obliterated when the original theme is updated.

Where can I change the text that is generated into the "colophon" div?

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the footer.php file from the parent theme folder to your child theme folder.
2. Edit your child theme footer.php.
3. Remove the php script and html markup inside the `<div id="colophon">` and replace it with whatever script or html you want.